# AngularJS - NgOptions from function returning undefined values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, undefined, angularjs-ng-options

I've got an application which has to show some options inside a `select` depending on a previous option. To achieve this, I've put the logic to show those options inside a controller function, like this:

```
vm.getScopeValues = function(tp){
    var vals = [];

    vals.push({n: 'Opt1', v: 'opt1'});

    if(!tp || tp != 'somevalue'){
        vals.push({n: 'Opt2', v: 'opt2'});
    }

    return vals;
};
```

The problem is that sometimes, I get an `undefined` as the value of the select options. On the following jsFiddle you can see a simpler approach, but with same result:

https://jsfiddle.net/nr9ffrkk/

As you can see:

- If I write `track by v`, I get undefined
- If I write `track by o.v`, then the values are right, but the `ng-model` does not get matched correctly
- If I write `o.v as o.n...` without the `track by`, I get an error ($digest cycles)
- When everything gets matched correctly (I achieved it somehow but cannot remember how), if I add a new dynamic "field" (click on "ADD NEW FIELD"), then they come out as `undefined` values again

I've made `console.log` to watch the returning values of the function, and it gets called correctly and returns the right values (nothing `undefined`).

I need to be able to create dinamycally new entries on the `fields` array (with an initial value for `type`, of course) and that the select gets the right values for the options.

### UPDATED

As you can see, making a controller variable (not a function) with the values does not work neither, bringing the same problem:

https://jsfiddle.net/dgy5ryvh/

Thank you!

Comment: This method is not correct. You are generating a new array at each call, angular  will not be able to find its private properties $$xx ($$hashObject i think) etc.. So it will believe the object has to be updated in the view. You have to put the result in scope.myoptionsvalues for example.

Comment: But I need a different set of options depending on the type of field. I cannot get a `$scope` fields variable, because this would change every instance on every field, taking as the correct values the last ones called.

Comment: you can put them in a subobject. `$scope.myoptions = {};` And for each object, you create `$scope.myoptions[objectIndex] = [];` and add the options in it. objectIndex can be the type name of your object or whatever you want, you need to store them else angularjs will not be able to know if the options have been updated.

Comment: Well, I'll try that approach. However, I would like to see if anyone else can come with a solution without having to pre-create those fields and storing their values into an array. Thank you!

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant I've tried your approach, but I'm still getting the same problem. I get `undefined` or get the correct values but an "?" option as the selected by default (instead of the `ng-model` value). Any other ideas? Thank you.

Comment: please give us an updated jsfiddle, with the problem

Comment: Done! You can see it working now here: https://jsfiddle.net/dgy5ryvh/ . Thank you!